# Can I use pip in a conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am using a conda environment to install a package and this package have dependencies that's not available in conda, so I have to use pip to install some additional packages in the conda environment. After I did all these:

I tested both:

```
pip list
```

and

```
conda list
```

And found that some dependencies occur in pip list but not in conda list. Is this OK? Do the packages installed by pip in conda enviroment also effect in this envorment?

Comment: What's about to try ```import <package>```? It will fail if the package is not installed

Comment: Check out the anacondas blog page: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use a combination of `pip install` and `conda install` when setting up the environment for a project I'm working on. It works fine.

However, it is documented here that this combination can lead to issues: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

According to that doc, you ought to first use conda to install as many of your packages as possible, then use pip to install the rest afterwards.

Comment: If you're able to suggest any clarifications or additions to my answer or a link to a more recent blog post, I'd be happy to edit my answer.